# How to import existing ECR repository into Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I've tried variations of the following tf file after reading these docs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecr_repository to import an existing ECR repository.

```
import {
  to = aws_ecr_repository.tamarack_api
  id = "arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/tamarack-api"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" tamarack_api {
  name = "tamarack-api"
}
```

`terraform plan` gives me this error:

> Error: reading ECR Repository (arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/tamarack-api): InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter at 'repositoryName' failed to satisfy constraint: 'must satisfy regular expression '(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[.*-][a-z0-9]+)*/)*[a-z0-9]+(?:[.*-][a-z0-9]+)*''

I tried that regex in https://regex101.com/ using the `Go` language, but it matches the string `tamarack-api`. Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: In the example you linked only the repository name is used, not the entire arn. Try using `id = "tamarack-api"`

Answer (score 1):

Id is only `tamarack-api`, not `arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:repository/tamarack-api`:

```
import {
  to = aws_ecr_repository.tamarack_api
  id = "tamarack-api"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a resource reference includes this `arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:` part then it is actually the [ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference-arns.html) not the name. [This](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc) VPC resource is a good example. The `name` of the VPC is like a tag, the `ID` is something like `vpc-abcdef` and the ARN would look like `arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:`.

It's helpful to know because some resources will allow you to have duplicate `name`s but the ARN is always unique.